# How many arrangements of the $26$ different letters are there that contain neither the sequence "the" nor the sequence "math"?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

Solve the following question via exclusion and inclusion principles. This question was a bit more tricky then other questions I have faced so I am wondering if my workings are correct, thanks!

> How many arrangements of the $26$ different letters are there that contain neither the sequence "the" nor the sequence "math"?

We know that there are $24!$ arrangements that contain 
the sequence "the", so there are $(26! - 24!)$ sequences that do not, as there 
are 26! arrangements without restrictions.

Next, considering "math" as one element, we can arrange this and the remaining 
22 letters in 23! ways. Thus there are $(26! - 23!)$ arrangements that do not contain the sequence "math".

Finally, we must consider those arrangements that contain the sequence "mathe", 
as we will have deducted these arrangements twice in the first $2$ steps. 
By similar reasoning to above, there are $22!$ arrangements that include "mathe", thus we will need to add $22!$ to the sum from the first $2$ steps.

This gives us a final answer of $\left[(26! - 24!) + (26! - 23!) + 22!\right]  $ arrangements.

Comment: Looks all good to me.

Comment: Did you mean to say neither the sequence "the" *nor* the sequence "math"?

Comment: yes I did, I will edit that in. Does it look correct to you?

Comment: Have you checked Dyck words and Catalan numbers? They count permutations avoiding patterns, that might give you another point of view

Comment: @N.F.Taussig an answer below says it looks wrong but I have more saying it looks correct

Comment: I withdraw my previous comment.  J. G. is correct that your answer is larger than the number of possible words, which I should have checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How many arrangements of the $26$ letters of the alphabet contain neither  "math" nor "the"?

Let $S$ denote the set of all permutations of the alphabet; let $M$ denote the set of all permutations of the alphabet that contain the subsequence *math*; let $T$ denote the set of all permutations of the alphabet that contain the subsequence *the*.

We wish to count all permutations in the alphabet that contain neither the subsequence *math* nor the subsequence *the*.  That is, we wish to count the number of elements in the set $M^C \cap T^C$.

Since $M^C \cap T^C = S - (M \cup T)$, 
$$|M^C \cap T^C| = |S| - |M \cup T|$$
By the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle,
$$|M \cup T| = |M| + |T| - |M \cap T|$$
Hence, 
$$|M^C \cap T^C| = |S| - |M| - |T| + |M \cap T|$$
You correctly found that 
\begin{align*}
|S| & = 26!\\
|M| & = 23!\\
|T| & = 24!\\
|M \cap T| & = 22!
\end{align*}
Hence, 
$$|M^C \cap T^C| = 26! - 23! - 24! + 22!$$

> Where did you go wrong?

You added the number of sequences that do not contain the subsequence *math*, the number of subsequences that do not contain the word *the*, and the number of subsequences that contain both *math* and *the*, that is,
$$|M^C| + |T^C| + |M \cap T|$$
Draw a Venn diagram as follows:  Draw a rectangle that includes two overlapping circles.  The rectangle represents the set $S$ of all permutations of the alphabet.  Label one of the circles, say the one on the left, $M$.  It represents the set of sequences that contain the subsequence *math*.  Label the other circle $T$.  It represents the set of sequences that contain the subsequence *the*.  The region where the two circles intersect is $M \cap T$.  The region inside the rectangles but outside the circles is $M^C \cap T^C$, which is what we want to count since is the set of sequences in $S$ that contain neither the subsequence *math* nor the subsequence *the*.

If we shade $M^C$ (with, say, lines from the lower left to the upper right), we shade everything in $S$ except for $M$.  Thus, we have already shaded $M^C \cap T^C$ and the part of set $T$ outside $M$.  If we now shade $T^C$ (with, say, lines from the upper left to the lower right), we shade everything in $M^C \cap T^C$ again and the region of $M$ outside $T$.  We then shade $M \cap T$ (with, say, horizontal lines).  Notice that we have now shaded $M \cup T$ once and $M^C \cap T^C$ twice.  Put another away, we have shaded all of $S$ once and then shaded $M^C \cap T^C$ a second time.  Consequently, what you counted is 
$$|M^C| + |T^C| + |M \cup T| = |S| + |M^C \cup T^C|$$
Using my answer above for $|M^C \cap T^C|$, we obtain 
$$|S| + |M^C \cap T^C| = 26! + 26! - 23! - 24! + 22!$$ 
which explains why you have an extra $26!$ term in your answer.

Comment: permutations and arrangements are they same thing correct?

Comment: and what does the $C$ mean when you say $M^C$

Comment: Yes, permutations are the same thing as arrangements, provided that you do not permit repetitions.  $M^C$ is one way of denoting the complement of set $M$, that is, the elements that are not in set $M$.

Comment: okay this is the explanations: 
$24!$ arrangements that contain the sequence "the", so there are $(26! - 24!)$ sequences that do not, as there are 26! arrangements without restrictions. 

considering "math" as one element, we can arrange this and the remaining 22 letters in 23! ways. Thus $23!$ arrangements. 

 Consider now those arrangements that contain the sequence "mathe", as we will have deducted these arrangements twice in the first $2$ steps. There are $22!$ arrangements that include "mathe", thus we will need to add $22!$ to the sum from the first $2$ steps.

Comment: I do not have time to respond.  Since I am traveling, I may not have access to a computer until tomorrow.  Please reread my solution so that you understand the logic behind it.  Best wishes.

Comment: okays thanks for your help! I will try and make some sense of it

Comment: @jh123 I have added an explanation of why your answer contains an extra $26!$ term.

Answer (score 4):

Not quite: you should only have one copy of $26!$ in the answer, as right now you have a result that's clearly larger than $26!$.

Comment: I have some saying this answer is correct

Comment: @jh123 I know you do, but they're all obviously wrong. You only need to ask whether you've got more than $26!$ permutations to see you've messed up the inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: **Strategy:**  There are $26!$ permutations of the letters of the alphabet.  Subtract those that violate one of the restrictions, then add those that violate both restrictions to see why the answer should be $26! - 24! - 23! + 22!$, as J.G. said.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig could you edit that into my answer for me? I am a little confused

Comment: @N.F.Taussig or post your own answer with detail